# Display word custom document property on screentip

Tags: windows, ms-word, tooltip, custom-properties

On your Windows machine if you just hover your mouse over any Microsoft Office Word 2007/2010 document you get a screentip which generally contains metadata information such as Type,Authors, Size and DateModified. These metadata are the builtin document properties of any word document.

I'm wondering if there is any (VSTO/other/hacked)way to display a custom document property on such a screentip.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you, you want to customize the windows explorer tooltips which are shown when hovering over Microsoft Word files?

This is possible using the registry. Specifically you can navigate to HKCR\Word.Document. and edit the InfoTip entry.

Specifics are descriped here: [Customize Windows Explorer Tooltips](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/02/10/customize-windows-explorer-tooltips/) and on a German page, very poorly translated via Google: [Windows XP: provide tooltip in Explorer with detailed information](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fpcwissen.net%2Ftooltip-im-explorer-mit-detail-informationen-ausstatten%2F&act=url).

Please note that this procedure may vary depending on your Office Version and your Windows version so you might want to look a little deeper into that.